# Standard Deviation: The average weight of a set X of 100 bags of rice is 90 pounds

Tags: standard-deviation

> [image]
>
> a. A>B
>
> b. A<B
>
> c. A=B
>
> d. Not enough info.

I chose D because 'normal distribution' is not written in the problem. Otherwise I would choose (b) because A = 42 and B > 48 (the different between -3σ and 3σ which is 114-66=48)

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

The answer is (d) according to the book, however, I don't understand any thing highlighted here:

> [image]

So please elucidate it if you could. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax rather than posting images.

Answer (score 1):

The weight of $A$ is $90-2\cdot 8=74$ pounds.  Bag $B$ weighs $90+5=95$ pounds.  It is unfortunate that they use $A$ and $B$ again for quantities that are not the weight of these bags, but quantity $A$ is $2(95-74)=42$ pounds as you found (though it would have been good to specify that it was the quantity and not the bag weight)

To prove $D$ is correct, you could show two distributions that have the given mean and standard deviation, one with a range less than $42$ and one with a range greater than $42$.  You need one bag with weight $74$ and one with weight $95$.  The minimum range is $21$ from bags $A$ and $B$.  You are $11$ pounds light for the average, so add in a bag at $101$ for a range of $37$ and enough bags at $90$ to bring the standard deviation down to $8$.  For one with greater range, add in bags of weights $60$ and $131$, which gets a range of $71$ and an average of $90$.  Again, add in enough bags at $90$ to bring the standard deviation down to $8$.  It will take a bunch, but that is OK.